# D3 axis origin changes as per its scales range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am a little confused on how D3s axis object takes its origin position and where it is anchored(I assume its top left)

Also it seem like the origin point changes as per the range of the associated scale for instance,the two axis below would start at different position

1st  axis

```
    //Xscale with scale not augmented       
    var stageXScale=d3.scaleLinear()            
      .domain([0,150])
      .range([0,150]);

    var stageXAxis = d3.axisBottom(stageXScale)   //unaug axis
        .ticks(20);
```

2nd axis

```
    //scale which is augmented
    var stageXScaleAug=d3.scaleLinear()            
      .domain([0,stageWidth])
      .range([0+stageMarginLeft,150+stageMarginLeft]);

    var stageXAxisAug = d3.axisBottom(stageXScaleAug)       //aug axis
        .ticks(20);
```

Isn't the origin of the axis  mapped to the origin of the parent container,if so why does the scale of the axis change this.
Here is Js fiddle example :

https://jsfiddle.net/Snedden27/3wsx8bdy/12/

Answer (score 1):

The position of the origin of the axis (prior to `transform`) is determined by the minimum value of the range of the scale.

For axis 1, the range is `[0,150]` and the axis starts at screen x-coordinate `0` of the parent element. (The axis ends at x-coordinate 150.)

For axis 2, the range is `[0+stageMarginLeft,150+stageMarginLeft]`, so that axis starts at screen x-coordinate `stageMarginLeft` (20) of the parent element.

Comment: is there a way I can always start an axis at the origin of the parent regarless of the scale

Comment: Why don't you just always start your scale's range with 0 in that case? That's the purpose of `range`. The range is the range of screen coordinates relative to the parent the axis will be shown over.